# Anyone notice that sometimes edits are not catalogued?

Tags: discussion, bug, edits, locked-votes, grace-period

By virtue of the nature of the question, I can't give concrete evidence, since I don't record my screen, but over the past few days, I've tried to change a downvote or an upvote after an edit has appeared (I know that an edit appeared, because the content of the post obviously changed), but SO has no record of such an edit, so I can't change my vote.  Anyone know what's going on here/experienced similar issues?

The only thing I can think of is that there's some sort of threshold for what constitutes an edit that is significant enough to warrant a record, but that seems to be flawed.  Or perhaps, there's a significant amount of lag between an edit and its recording, but that doesn't appear to be true from my experience.

---

Apparently there's a five-minute grace period, in which edits are not logged, but it makes no sense to me that I can vote one way, you can change your answer, and if this occurs in a certain time period, then I cannot change my vote unless an additional edit has been made.

---

The other posts, while very similar to this one, seem to be more concerned with when you want to **undo** a down vote, but what if the opposite is true and there isn't an incentive for the OP to change their post (I'm concerned with both issues).  The quick fix is to edit the question and change your vote, which seems inappropriate.  There should be a non-hackish way to do this.

Comment: Did the edit happen with five minutes of the post creation?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins It's quite possible.  If that's the case, though, it makes sense to me that I should be able to change my vote if they change their answer, regardless of when an edit occured.

Comment: There is a five minute "grace period" during which edits are not logged. I'm not sure how that affects the ability to change votes. Perhaps someone else can speak to that issue.

Comment: I looked at the other questions, and thought that they were the same, but they died out and nothing came as a result, so I think that closing this question wouldn't really help anyone.  Additionally, as can be seen in my edit, what about the issue that arises when someone originally posts something correct, makes a change that is not recorded and is factually incorrect or radically changes the post, and doesn't make additional edits?  Then one cannot change their vote unless they make an edit, which may not be called for.  This seems like a loophole and not a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: If you look at the second question (mine is actually a dupe of that), you'll notice it has been marked status-bydesign. So although I agree with you, I doubt this will be changed.